# Developing QGIS plugin: AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5, pyqt4

I was tasked with making a small plugin for QGIS or add a small functionality to an existing one.

What I am trying to do is take the "geocode with web service" from the plugin MMQGIS
and add a button that opens a new dialog window with an option to split a CSV file

I first created a plugin to split a CSV file using plugin builder. Now I am trying to add the existing code for  "geocode with web service"
and I get some errors  like:

```
'NewMmqgis' object has no attribute 'dlg2'
```

and

```
'mmqgis_geocode_web_service_dialog' object has no attribute 'status'
```

I can't understand where the problem is.
I think `setupUI` doesn't set up the attributes for my `mmqgis_geocode_web_service_dialog`
but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code for dialogs:

`new_mmqgis_dialog.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 NewMmqgisDialog
                                 A QGIS plugin
 upgraded version of mmqgis geocode function
 Generated by Plugin Builder: http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/
                             -------------------
        begin                : 2022-01-14
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
      
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""

import os
import pandas as pd
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.PyQt import uic
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

# Used instead of "import math" so math functions can be used without "math." prefix
from math import *

# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'mmqgis_geocode_csv_spliter_form.ui'))
FORM_CLASS2, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'new_mmqgis_dialog_base.ui'))


class NewMmqgisDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(NewMmqgisDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        # After self.setupUi() you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Apply).clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Close).clicked.connect(self.reject)
        self.input_csv_name.fileChanged.connect(self.set_csv_attributes)

        chars = [".", ",", "space", "-", "/", ";", "'"]
        self.comboBox_2.clear()
        self.comboBox_2.addItems(chars)
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def set_csv_attributes(self):
        self.comboBox.clear()
        self.comboBox.addItem("(none)")
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)

        input_csv = QgsVectorLayer(str(self.input_csv_name.filePath()))

        if len(input_csv.fields()) <= 0:
            # self.comboBox.addItem(str(self.input_csv_split.filePath()))
            return

        for index, field in enumerate(input_csv.fields()):
            field_name = field.name()
            self.comboBox.addItem(field_name)

    def run(self):
        input_csv_name = str(self.input_csv_name.filePath()).strip()
        column = ""
        if self.comboBox.currentText() and (self.comboBox.currentText() != "(none)"):
            column = str(self.comboBox.currentText()).strip()

        char = str(self.comboBox_2.currentText()).strip()
        message = mmqgis_split_column(input_csv_name, column, char)
        if message == None:
            QMessageBox.critical(self.iface.mainWindow(), "errore", message)
        self.accept()


class mmqgis_geocode_web_service_dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(mmqgis_geocode_web_service_dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mmqgis_set_status_bar(self.status)
        self.buttonBox.button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Apply).clicked.connect(self.run)
        # self.editButton.clicked.connect(self.edit_cvs_file)

        self.input_csv_name.fileChanged.connect(self.set_csv_attributes)

        web_services = ["Google", "OpenStreetMap / Nominatim", "US Census Bureau", "ESRI Server", "NetToolKit"]
        self.web_service.clear()
        self.web_service.addItems(web_services)
        self.web_service.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.web_service.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.service_changed)

        self.duplicate_handling.addItems(["Use Only First Result", "Multiple Features for Multiple Results"])

        self.mmqgis_initialize_spatial_output_file_widget(self.output_file_name)

        self.mmqgis_initialize_tabular_output_file_widget(self.not_found_file_name)

    def mmqgis_set_status_bar(self, status_bar):
        status_bar.setMinimum(0)
        status_bar.setMaximum(100)
        status_bar.setValue(0)
        status_bar.setFormat("Ready")
        self.status_bar = status_bar

    def service_changed(self):
        if str(self.web_service.currentText()).strip() == "ESRI Server":
            self.api_key_label.setText("ESRI Server URL")

            self.api_key.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.api_key_label.setText("API Key")

            self.api_key.setEnabled(str(self.web_service.currentText()).strip()
                                    in ["Google", "NetToolKit"])

        self.parameter_attribute_4.setEnabled(str(self.web_service.currentText()).strip() != "US Census Bureau")

    def set_csv_attributes(self):
        combolist = [self.parameter_attribute_1, self.parameter_attribute_2,
                     self.parameter_attribute_3, self.parameter_attribute_4]

        for box in combolist:
            box.clear()
            box.addItem("(none)")
            box.setCurrentIndex(0)

        input_csv = QgsVectorLayer(str(self.input_csv_name.filePath()))

        if len(input_csv.fields()) <= 0:
            return

        for index, field in enumerate(input_csv.fields()):
            field_name = field.name()

            for box in combolist:
                box.addItem(field_name)

            if field_name.lower().find("addr") >= 0:
                self.parameter_attribute_1.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)
            if field_name.lower().find("street") >= 0:
                self.parameter_attribute_2.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)

            if field_name.lower().find("city") >= 0:
                self.parameter_attribute_2.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)

            if field_name.lower().find("state") >= 0:
                self.parameter_attribute_3.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)
            if field_name.lower() == "st":
                self.parameter_attribute_3.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)
            if field_name.lower().find("province") >= 0:
                self.parameter_attribute_3.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)

            if field_name.lower().find("country") >= 0:
                self.parameter_attribute_4.setCurrentIndex(index + 1)

    def run(self):
        input_csv_name = str(self.input_csv_name.filePath()).strip()

        parameters = []
        if self.parameter_attribute_1.currentText() and (self.parameter_attribute_1.currentText() != "(none)"):
            parameters.append((str(self.parameter_name_1.text()).strip(),
                               str(self.parameter_attribute_1.currentText()).strip()))

        if self.parameter_attribute_2.currentText() and (self.parameter_attribute_2.currentText() != "(none)"):
            parameters.append((str(self.parameter_name_2.text()).strip(),
                               str(self.parameter_attribute_2.currentText()).strip()))

        if self.parameter_attribute_3.currentText() and (self.parameter_attribute_3.currentText() != "(none)"):
            parameters.append((str(self.parameter_name_3.text()).strip(),
                               str(self.parameter_attribute_3.currentText()).strip()))

        if self.parameter_attribute_4.currentText() and (self.parameter_attribute_4.currentText() != "(none)"):
            parameters.append((str(self.parameter_name_4.text()).strip(),
                               str(self.parameter_attribute_4.currentText()).strip()))

        web_service = str(self.web_service.currentText()).strip()

        api_key = str(self.api_key.displayText()).strip()

        if (api_key == "(none)") or (api_key == ""):
            api_key = None

        use_first = str(self.duplicate_handling.currentText()) == "Use Only First Result"

        output_file_name = str(self.output_file_name.filePath())
        not_found_file_name = self.not_found_file_name.filePath()

        message = mmqgis_geocode_web_service(input_csv_name, parameters, web_service, api_key, use_first,
                                             output_file_name, not_found_file_name, self.mmqgis_status_callback)

        if message != None:
            QMessageBox.critical(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Web Service Geocode", message)

        elif self.mmqgis_find_layer_by_data_source(output_file_name):
            self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()

        else:
            self.iface.addVectorLayer(output_file_name, "", "ogr")


def mmqgis_split_column(csv, column, char):
    data1 = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding='ISO-8859-8')
    data1 = pd.concat([data1, data1[column].str.split(char, expand=True)], axis=1)
    outfile = csv.split('.')[0] + "_split." + csv.split('.')[1]
    data1.to_csv(outfile, encoding='ISO-8859-8', index=False)
    return outfile


def mmqgis_geocode_web_service(input_csv_name, parameter_attributes, web_service, api_key, use_first,
                               output_file_name, not_found_file_name, status_callback=None):
#indentical to mmqgis's function
```

Here is my code for the plugin:

`new_mmqgis.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 NewMmqgis
                                 A QGIS plugin
 upgraded version of mmqgis geocode function
 Generated by Plugin Builder: http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2022-01-14
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
        copyright            : (C) 2022 by beni segal
        email                : bs108@walla.co.il
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .new_mmqgis_dialog import *
import os.path


class NewMmqgis:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'NewMmqgis_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&new mmqgis geocoder')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('NewMmqgis', message)

    def mmqgis_add_submenu(self, submenu):
        if self.mmqgis_menu != None:
            self.mmqgis_menu.addMenu(submenu)
        else:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&mmqgis", submenu.menuAction())

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""
        self.mmqgis_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(QCoreApplication.translate("mmqgis", "MMQGIS"))
        self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(self.iface.firstRightStandardMenu().menuAction(), self.mmqgis_menu)

        self.geocode_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(QCoreApplication.translate("mmqgis", "&Geocode"))
        self.mmqgis_add_submenu(self.geocode_menu)

        icon = QIcon('icon.png')
        self.geocode_web_service_action = QtWidgets.QAction(icon, "Geocode CSV with Web Service",
                                                            self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.geocode_web_service_action.triggered.connect(self.geocode_web_service)
        self.geocode_menu.addAction(self.geocode_web_service_action)

        icon = QIcon('icon.png')
        self.geocode_csv_spliter_action = QtWidgets.QAction(icon, "Csv spliter", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.geocode_csv_spliter_action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.geocode_menu.addAction(self.geocode_csv_spliter_action)

        # icon_path = ':/plugins/new_mmqgis/icon.png'
        # self.add_action(
        #     icon_path,
        #     text=self.tr(u'split CSV'),
        #     callback=self.run,
        #     parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        if self.mmqgis_menu != None:
            self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().removeAction(self.mmqgis_menu.menuAction())
        else:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu("&mmqgis", self.geocode_menu.menuAction())



    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = NewMmqgisDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass


    def geocode_web_service(self):
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg2 = mmqgis_geocode_web_service_dialog()

            # show the dialog
        self.dlg2.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg2.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

For now, the CSV splitter is in a different submenu for testing.
I tested and it works just fine. However, I can't get the geocode with web service to work for now.
The UI is identical to mmqgis plugin with the addition of 1 button named `editButton` which is disabled for now.
So it does have a `qprogressbar` element named `status`.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I resorted to building a new  plugin with plugin builder instead of  building on the original mmqgis plugin because of a similar error.

Comment: What is `self.status`? A widget in`new_mmqgis_dialog_base.ui`?

Answer (score 6):

In `new_mmqgis.py`:

You set `self.first_start = True` in `initGui`, then, you set `self.first_start = False` in `run` method.
In `geocode_web_service` method, you are checking `if self.first_start == True`. That `if` block never runs because `self.first_start=False`. That is the reason of getting '`NewMmqgis' object has no attribute 'dlg2'` error.

One solution to this would be to remove the following two lines and unindent the third one in `geocode_web_service` method.

```
if self.first_start == True: # REMOVE
    self.first_start = False # REMOVE

<-  self.dlg2 = mmqgis_geocode_web_service_dialog() # UNINDENT
```

For the second error, you probably didn't add a status bar named `status`. Check `new_mmqgis_dialog_base.ui` file.